# Linear programming vertex proof

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I want to prove that $x$ is vertex of $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\ \colon Ax\leqslant b, \ x\geqslant 0\}$ iff $(x,b-Ax)$ is the vertex of $\{(x,u)\in \mathbb{R}^{n+m}\ \colon Ax+u=b, \ x\geqslant 0, \ u\geqslant 0\}$. Here $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix.

Definition is: $x \in X$ is called a vertex of a set $X$ if $x$ can't be represented as $x=\lambda y+(1-\lambda)z$, where $y,z\in X$, $y\neq z$ and $\lambda\in (0,1)$.

Any ideas?

Comment: $z$ does not appear in your definition of a *vertex*

Comment: Second section is only the definition. For clarification.

Comment: Usually including your thoughts and telling us where do you get stucked receive better responses from the community.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the first polyhedral as $P_1$ and the second polyhedral be $P_2$.

**Part 1:**

Suppose $x \in P_1$ is not a vertex of $P_1$, then $\exists y,z \in P_1$ such that $$x=\lambda y+(1-\lambda)z$$

check that $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ b-Ax \end{pmatrix}\in P_2$

and we have $$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ b-Ax \end{pmatrix}=\lambda \begin{pmatrix}y \\b-Ay \end{pmatrix}+(1-\lambda )\begin{pmatrix}z \\b-Az \end{pmatrix}$$

Notice that $y \in P_1 \implies \begin{pmatrix}y \\b-Ay \end{pmatrix} \in P_2$ and $z \in P_1 \implies \begin{pmatrix}z \\b-Az \end{pmatrix} \in P_2.$

Hence $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ b-Ax \end{pmatrix} \in P_2$ is not a vertex of $P_2$.

**Part 2:**

Conversely, if $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ b-Ax \end{pmatrix} \in P_2$ is not a vertex of $P_2$, then $\exists \begin{pmatrix} y \\ u_u \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} z \\ u_z \end{pmatrix} \in P_2$.

From definition of $P_2$, we can deduce that $u_y=b-Ay$ and $u_z=b-Az$ and we have

$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ b-Ax \end{pmatrix}=\lambda \begin{pmatrix}y \\b-Ay \end{pmatrix}+(1-\lambda )\begin{pmatrix}z \\b-Az \end{pmatrix}$$

and we have $$x=\lambda y+(1-\lambda ) z$$

we have to check that $y,z \in P_1$, are you able to prove this?

If you can achieve this, you have proven that $x$ is not a vertex of $P_1$.

**Summary:**

$x \in P_1$ is not a vertex of $P_1$ if and of if $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ b-Ax \end{pmatrix} \in P_2$ is not a vertex of $P_2$

$x \in P_1$ is a vertex of $P_1$ if and of if $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ b-Ax \end{pmatrix} \in P_2$ is a vertex of $P_2$